# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint on SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following code in controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string imei)
{
    var device = await _dbContext.Devices.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Imei == imei);
    if (device == null)
    {
        await _dbContext.Devices.AddAsync(new Device(imei));
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ConflictException($"Device with IMEI '{imei}' already exists");
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

It is hard to reproduce but sometimes I got

> 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   \"devices_imei_key\"

It seems that `device` is null but when `SaveChanges` it is already not null. How can I handle it avoid using `try...catch`? Can I use `AsNoTacking()` to improve reading from database?

Comment: This could be a [time-of-check to time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) issue - when you check it doesn't exist, but when you come to save it it has been created already. How many devices does your app add?

Comment: Yeah, seems it is. about 10 per minute but sometimes to 10 per second

Comment: If this is how your application is set to behave, i.e you could have a device set up in between your checking for it and you saving it - I can't think of an easier way to deal with it other than a `try catch` with the specific exception for  the duplicate key. Another option - create a stored procedure for inserting new devices and handle this scenario in there - but at some level you will have to deal with the exception.

Comment: could you please explain more about "have a device set up in between your checking for it and you saving it". thanks

Comment: @Chebur - I meant that a new device is being set up between you checking for it and you trying to save it - which is the scenario you are describing above.

Comment: Your application is throwing an error incase a device with this imei already exists and this is how it should work, I am not sure whats the problem here?

Comment: @FakharAhmadRasul It is problem because it should throw ConflictException instead of  500 Internal Server Error with text "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"devices_imei_key\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic concurrency and as always, you need to have a specific strategy for handling concurrency. The method you're currently using is insufficient unless you gate the logic, such that only one request can go through the pipeline at a time, using a semaphore. That skirts the issue of concurrency, but obviously has an impact on performance, as you're creating a choke point in your application.

Your best bet here, since you have the unique constraint, is to wrap the code in a try/catch and actually handle the scenario you're facing. Since there should only be one entry for each IMEI, you can simply do the same as you're doing in the else block for the catch block: return a `ConflictException`.

For this particular issue, there is no other options but adding a lock or handling the exception (using try/catch). It doesn't matter how "fast" you go, there is *always* a potential for a concurrency conflict, and you'll need to handle that.